# Azure Data Factory: output dataset file name from input dataset folder name

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to solve following scenario in Azure Data Factory:

I have a large number of folders in Azure Blob Storage. Each folder contains varying number of files in parquet format. Folder name contains the date when data contained in the folder was generated, something like this: DATE=2021-01-01. I need to filter the files and save them into another container in delimited format and each file should have the date indicated in source folder name in it's file name.

So when my input looks something like this...

```
DATE=2021-01-01/
    data-file-001.parquet
    data-file-002.parquet
    data-file-003.parquet
DATE=2021-01-02/
    data-file-001.parquet
    data-file-002.parquet
```

...my output should look something like this:

```
output-data/
    data_2021-01-01_1.csv
    data_2021-01-01_2.csv
    data_2021-01-01_3.csv
    data_2021-01-02_1.csv
    data_2021-01-02_2.csv
```

Reading files from subfolders and filtering them and saving them is easy. Problems start when I'm trying to set output dataset file name dynamically. I can get the folder names using Get Metadata activity and then I can use ForEach activity to set them into variables. However, I can't figure out how to use this variable in filtering data flow sinks dataset.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
My **Get Metadata1** activity, set the container `input` as:
[image]
Set the container `input` as follows:
[image]
My debug info is as follows:
[image]

I think I've found the solution. I'm using csv files for example.
My input looks something like this

```
container:input 
    2021-01-01/
      data-file-001.csv
      data-file-002.csv
      data-file-003.csv
    2021-01-02/
      data-file-001.csv
      data-file-002.csv
```

My debug result is as follows:
[image]

[image]

1. Using `Get Metadata1` activity to get the folder list and then using `ForEach1` activity to iterate this list.
   [image]
2. Inside the `ForEach1` activity, we now using data flow to move data.
   [image]
3. Set the source dataset to the container and declare a parameter `FolderName`.
   [image]
4. Then add dynamic content `@dataset().FolderName` to the source dataser.
   [image]
5. Back to the `ForEach1` activity, we can add dynamic content `@item().name` to parameter `FolderName`.
   [image]
6. Key in `File_Name` to the tab. It will store the file name as a column eg. `/2021-01-01/data-file-001.csv`.
   [image]
7. Then we can process this column to get the file name we want via `DerivedColumn1`.
   Addd expression `concat('data_',substring(File_Name,2,10),'_',split(File_Name,'-')[5])`.
   [image]
8. In the Settings of sink, we can select `Name file as column data` and `File_Name`.
   [image]

That's all.

Comment: I replicated your suggestion but I'm still having problems. I'm not sure if I'm using different version or something but when adding FolderName parameter, I need to define default value as well. If I leave it blank, I'm getting error message on debug run. If I set initial value to first folder containing the files, Get Metadata activity gets filenames from that folder instead of folder list.

Comment: Hi , because the value of the FolderName parameter is dynamically obtained. I used to set '2021-01-01' as the default value for data flow preview. Then I deleted it.